# Difference between org.json.simple and org.json

Tags: java, arrays, json

```
JSONArray js1 = new JSONArray();
for (Product product : plist) {
    JSONObject jo1 = new JSONObject();
    jo1.put("image", product.getProductImages());
    jo1.put("name", product.getName());
    jo1.put("price", product.getPrice());

    js1.add(jo1);
}
```

In the above code I can not use `js1.add(jo1);` because of I import these Libraries.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

but if I import these

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

I can use `add` method.
 
So what is the difference between these `org.json.simple`. and  `org.json`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different dependencies on your classpath.

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Above two imports come from [JSON-java](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java)

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

Above two imports come from [json-simple](https://code.google.com/archive/p/json-simple/)

These are two different implementation of JSON processor. So, it's obvious that the contract of these two dependencies don't match. There are other JSON processor listed on [json.org](http://json.org/).